# .htaccess every single file NOT found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server

Every single file is not found with .htaccess. Yet, I can normally access any of the files in question. Also .htaccess is in same folder as any of these files.

For example: If I enter https://example.com/post.php it works fine

But if I try with pretty link (leads to same file post.php) for example: https://example.com/vijest/slug/123 server responds with 404, file not found.

Same happens with any other pretty link, files do exit, but when accessed via .htaccess, server responds with 404.

Can you help me please?

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ [NC]

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule    ^vijest/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$    post.php?idNum=$2    [NC,L]
```

**UPDATE 1**

I copied working example from same server, but other project, and it did not work... But I am 1000000000% certain that these files do exist in specified path.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a detailed and full explanation of what you're trying to do is and what actually happens. Have you enabled `AllowOverride All` in your Apache vhost to allow for htaccess-files? Have you restarted Apache after making changes to any Apache config?

Comment: I edited my question, hope it is more clear now.  And yes AllowOverride All is enabled. No need for apache restart since I have not made any changes in config.

Comment: I would edit question and add only two example links into `.htaccess` instead of full htaccess which is hard to read, as a just advice you migth need to use `Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: Here is my edit again, with only one relevant RewriteRule. I metioned this rule in my question. I did try your Options +FollowSymLinks and still the same, response is 404.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass second param to .htaccess like this : `post.php?idNum=$1&q=2` first param is uniqe id, second param is `url` string.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^vijest/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$   post.php?idNum=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^vijest/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$    post.php?idNum=$1&q=2    [NC,L]
```

Your url should be saved in db like so : `how-to-create-seo-url`

and your php link should be like : `<a href="vijest/<?php echo $row["news_url"];?>">See More</a>`

in `post.php` page : `$_GET['idNum'];` AND Then your query `echo $_GET['idNum'];`

Here is the result : https://ibb.co/YDxQ8Mf and two parameters : https://ibb.co/XSZnSMJ

Make sure if your post.php is in root folder with htaccess.

Comment: Still 404 :S :'( I literally copied and pasted your code

Comment: @Korovjov you cant copy and paste my code, you need get parameters in landing page and edit parameters to your needs. Check this site for tutorial and tutorials on google https://www.askapache.com/category/htaccess/ you dont have this parameter &q=2 and not capturing it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I really appreciate it. Indeed, I did adjust a little bit, but this vijest/... actually is what suits me, and I tested that. Still 404.

Comment: @Korovjov Try this `RewriteRule    ^vijest/   post.php   [NC,L]` and let me know

Comment: 404... But here is the proof that this file do exist in the same folder https://ibb.co/5RBMNRt

Comment: @Korovjov I updated answer copy paste mine in to your htacces (only mine). AND importand mine uses seo_url

Comment: I am so sorry to disappoint you but still 404. And I did as you said https://ibb.co/7CL6bTf

Comment: @Korovjov show me your output url (if you are using seo urls) and url in php please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205345/discussion-between-korovjov-and-dilek).

Comment: I already am using all as you mentioned above in the most recent answer. Thank you for your, patience. Problem still persists, and the problem is: my .htaccess claims that there is no post.php file, hence 404.

Comment: Ok, I get that, but my url MUST be in format vijest/some-slug-url/123. /some-slug-url/ is slug from db, /123 is of content. This is mandatory because this website uses this kind of link for very long time and its links have been shared for a long time. I can't afford to make backward compatibility for other reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your help, really. Unfortunately it's still 404. But thank you, you were really kind for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone goes through this thread, my problem was with file name. 
Instead of htaccess, it was named htaccesss. If you open shared screenshots you' ll be able to see.

Thank you.